# CiviCrm Custom Fields - Random Number Generation

Tags: custom-fields, civicrm-home

Is there anyway to generate a random number using Custom Fields in Civi. any Ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I have a drush script I've used to assign lottery numbers into a civicrm custom field, I'd be happy to share that with you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to do that, but it would be an easy extension.  Could you give a bit of background about how you would use the random numbers?